# Implement METAPOST in Blockly

Tags: metapost

Has anyone looked into this?

Blockly is a visual code editor developed by Google: https://developers.google.com/blockly/

and at least one graphical language, OpenSCAD has been implemented: https://www.blockscad3d.com/

If not METAPOST, what would be the best graphical drawing language to implement?

Comment: Maybe Asymptote or SVG would be sufficiently modular and hierarchical for a visual code editor approach. However, I think it depends very much on your use case which language, if any, would be suitable: who are your users, what do they want to draw, what do they want/need to learn, which output formats are useful for them, etc.

Comment: I'm hoping to make something which will allow me to integrate OpenSCAD and some sort of vector drawing tool in an elegant and robust fashion --- managed to code up a project which allows one to design in OpenSCAD, then import those settings into lualatex via JSON and output a PDF: https://community.carbide3d.com/t/cnc-finger-joint-box/8880/89 --- if some sort of 2D drawing tool were so available I could re-use code more easily.